# Как обратиться к полю массива вложенного в массив JSON?

Tags: android, json, android-studio, kotlin

Как обратиться к полю массива вложенного в массив JSON? Мне необходимо получить значение поля "value" из массива "rows"->"elements"->"distance"->"value"

> JSON https://api.myjson.com/bins/1dzkgl

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [
      "ул. 2-й Луч, 5а, Санкт-Петербург, Россия, 192019"
   ],
   "origin_addresses" : [
      "ул. Книпович, 11, Санкт-Петербург, Россия, 192019"
   ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "0,4 км",
                  "value" : 443
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "1 мин.",
                  "value" : 70
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Есть такой рабочий пример, но не могу никак добраться по аналогии со своим.

```
{
  "data": "dbfriends",
  "friends": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Andrew",
      "city": "Moscow",
      "contacts": {
        "mobile": "+7 0000000",
        "email": "andrew@androiddocs.ru",
        "skype": "andrew"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Ivan",
      "city": "Kiev",
      "contacts": {
        "mobile": "+38 0000000",
        "email": "ivan@androiddocs.ru",
        "skype": "ivan"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

```
package com.example.sfp.javaparsejson

import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log

import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject

import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.URL


class MainActivity : ActionBarActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ParseTask().execute()
    }

    private inner class ParseTask : AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

        internal var urlConnection: HttpURLConnection? = null
        internal var reader: BufferedReader? = null
        internal var resultJson = ""

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void): String {
            // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса
            try {
                val url = URL("http://androiddocs.ru/api/friends.json")

                urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                urlConnection!!.requestMethod = "GET"
                urlConnection!!.connect()

                val inputStream = urlConnection!!.inputStream
                val buffer = StringBuffer()

                reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))

                var line: String?
/*                while ((line = reader!!.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line)
                }*/
                do {
                    line = reader!!.readLine()
                    if (line == null)
                        break
                    buffer.append(line)
                } while (true)

                resultJson = buffer.toString()

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            return resultJson
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(strJson: String) {
            super.onPostExecute(strJson)
            // выводим целиком полученную json-строку
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, strJson)

            var dataJsonObj: JSONObject? = null
            var secondName = ""

            try {
                dataJsonObj = JSONObject(strJson)
                val friends = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("friends")

                // 1. достаем инфо о втором друге - индекс 1
                val secondFriend = friends.getJSONObject(1)
                secondName = secondFriend.getString("name")
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Второе имя: " + secondName)

                // 2. перебираем и выводим контакты каждого друга
                for (i in 0..friends.length() - 1) {
                    val friend = friends.getJSONObject(i)

                    val contacts = friend.getJSONObject("contacts")

                    val phone = contacts.getString("mobile")
                    val email = contacts.getString("email")
                    val skype = contacts.getString("skype")

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "phone: " + phone)
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "email: " + email)
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "skype: " + skype)
                }

            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

        }
    }

    companion object {

        var LOG_TAG = "my_log"
    }
}
```

---

Ответ из комментариев (Сообщение: No value for value)

```
dataJSON = JSONObject(strJson)
                val rows = dataJSON.getJSONArray("rows")
                val obj = rows.getJSONObject(0)

                val elements = obj.getJSONArray("elements")
                val distance = elements.getJSONObject(0)

                val value = distance.getJSONObject("value")
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Text: " + value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код на kotlin:

```
val resultJson = JSONObject(responseString)

val rows = resultJson.getJSONArray("rows")
val obj = rows.getJSONObject(0)
val elements = obj.getJSONArray("elements")
val element = elements.getJSONObject(0)
val distance = element.getJSONObject("distance")
val value = distance.getInt("value")
```

И вообще, хоть вы (как я понял) и только начали обучение, всё же некоторые рутинные вопросы будет гораздо проще решить с помощью сторонних библиотек. Асинктаски это, конечно, хорошо и важно, но гораздо проще было бы решить вашу проблему вот так:

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
        .build()

val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .build()

client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
            val responseString = response!!.body()!!.string()

            val resultJson = JSONObject(responseString)

            val rows = resultJson.getJSONArray("rows")
            val obj = rows.getJSONObject(0)
            val elements = obj.getJSONArray("elements")
            val element = elements.getJSONObject(0)
            val distance = element.getJSONObject("distance")
            val value = distance.getInt("value")

            Log.d(TAG, "'value': " + value);
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "some error");
        }
    })
```

Использована библиотека [OkHttp](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp).

Comment: Сообщение: No value for value. Код на kotlin в вопросе.

Comment: @userBuzzer исправил.

Comment: responseString - неизвестный аргумент. Раньше я с JSON дел не имел вовсе. Библиотеки хорошо, но за отсутствием опыта использования их на котлине, отваливается код в различных местах, тем самым приходится искать другие решения.

Comment: @userBuzzer у вас есть опыт с Java? Если да, то какая разница, использовать библиотеки на котлине или на ней? Я привел кусок кода полностью рабочий, если используете только часть с разбором JSON-a, то `responseString` замените у себя в коде на вашу `strJson` и все проблемы решатся.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне помогла библиотека OkHttp. И даже не отвалилась, хотя я её недавно пробовал использовать...

Comment: Опыт с Java есть. На Java всё хорошо работает, а вот с Kotlin падает...